# Shifted overflowing div Mozilla Firefox Margin

Tags: html, css

I want to code a shifted div as here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQQdaL

Relevant css:

```
.wrap {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    width: 50%;
}

.image {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: -5%;
    width: 55%;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #fed2db, #212353);
}
```

this works for me just fine in Chrome/Safari but not in Firefox. Is there something I am missing?

This is what it should look like:

[image: Shifted Div Chrome]

This is what it looks like in Firefox:

[image: Not Shifted Div Firefox]

```css
.section {
  background: black;
  padding: 4em 0;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  top: 5%;
  margin-left: -5%;
  width: 55%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #fed2db, #212353);
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="wrap">

    <div class="box">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div class="image"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like a mix between the two in Chrome/Canary

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems primarily due to the lack of absolute height. I couldn't produce a clean single reason for the behavior, but in the meantime, [I recreated the intended result in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/forssa/js9km557/). Hope this helps.

JSFiddle code:

```css
.section {
  background: black;
  padding: 4em 0;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: green;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 45%;
  width: 55%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #fed2db, #212353);
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="wrap">

    <div class="box">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div class="image"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: I made the box blue.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I fixed the problem simply by giving the margin top an actual px value instead of a percentage value.